# dlsym() returns 'symbol not found'

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dynamic-loading, dlsym

I'm using OS X 10.7 (Lion), XCode 4.6.3 and libstdc++ as the C++ Standard Library.

I have this code in my main project:

shared.cpp:

```
extern "C" int sharedFun()
{
    return 5;
}
```

And this in my side project, that needs to dynamically load the main one:

loader.cpp:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    void* mainApp = dlopen("mainApp.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);

    char* error;
    dlsym(mainApp, "sharedFun");

    if ((error = dlerror()) != nullptr)
    {
         ....
    }
}
```

nm output:

```
nm -gU mainApp.dylib | grep sharedFun
002a3a10 - 01 0000   FUN _sharedFun
002a3a10 T _sharedFun
```

dlopen loads the library just fine, but dlsym returns "symbol not found".
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you assigning the return value of `dlsym()` to a variable?

Comment: I am (in my original code), but it is irrelevant here.

Comment: Sure, but you probably need to assure viewers of your question that you are checking for error by checking for a null return from `dlsym()` rather than relying on `dlerror()` alone.  If nothing else, it avoids questions like mine.

Comment: Are you sure that `dlopen` is successfully opening your library?

Comment: Do you have a typo in your real code as well?

Comment: the mainApp handle is not null after the dlopen line, and when checking dlerror right after dlopen, it returns null.

Comment: molbdnilo, what typo? (Obviously it compiles and runs just fine)

Comment: Is that because of the *lazy flag*?

Comment: Scratch that *again*. dlopen is working. I also tried the other NOW | GLOBAL variations, still no go.

Comment: shared.cpp calls it `sharedFunc`. Is this intentional?

Comment: It was a typo in the post and not in the code. Fixed.